# Laravel whereBetween with optional parameter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to construct query using `whereBetween` clause, but with a twist for which i didn't find a answer applicable in my case. I need, for when `from` parameter isn't present to regard that as to query from beginning. If `to` parameter isn't present, then needs to look everything after previously mentioned parameter.

Query currently:

```
Vehicle::whereBetween("updated_at", [$dates->start_date, $dates->end_date])->with("something")->get();
```

How i wanted it to be:

```
Vehicle::whereBetween("updated_at", "lookup from start date if present, if not, look from beginning", "lookup to said end date if it's present, if not, look up till the end"])->with("something")->get();
```

I am asking, what is appropriate to put in, when parameter isn't present so it works in way i described?

**Edit**:
If omitted, start date, query works fine. If end date gets omitted, query return zero in best case scenario. Worst case, throws an error.
I tried putting `null`, empty string, false, zero(0), for end date, nothing works.

Comment: `whereBetween`  must have two parameters start date & end date, if you have optional parameters try using different `if` condition and `where` clause.

Comment: When you say `from` and `to` are you referring to the `$dates->start_date` and `$dates->end_date` values? If so, please can you show where your getting/setting `$dates`.

Comment: @Rwd I'm sending them from Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make more sense to not use `whereBetween` and simply add `where` clauses conditionally. You could do this with the [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) method:

```
Vehicle::with("something")
    ->when($dates->start_date, function ($query, $date) {
        $query->where('updated_at', '>=', $date);
    })
    ->when($dates->end_date, function ($query, $date) {
        $query->where('updated_at', '<=', $date);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: It works this way. Not to sound ungrateful, i was looking more elegant way, but man ... They need to include "optional parameters" thing in every clause.